# Get Rest Api not returning JSON string correct format?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm use REST to get a url resource which returns a string, as follows:

```
URL url = new URL(some_url_string);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
reader.close();

String s = response.toString();
```

And I try to convert it into my class:

```
MyClass temp = new Gson().fromJson(s, MyClass.class);
```

where MyClass is:

```
public class MyClass {
    @SerializedName("Number")
    public int number;

    @SerializedName("Date")
    public Long date;
}
```

The problem is that `response.toString()` is returning:

```
"{\"Number\":2,\"Date\":1444953600}"
```

whilst, Gson expects a string as:

```
{"Number":2,"Date":1444953600}
```

Because `response.toString()` is returning the above string with additional `"` at the beginning and end of the string, I'm getting the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
>
> at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
>
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210)

Is the issue here the `GET`, `response.toString()` or `fromJson()`?

Comment: Try to set connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); will JsonObject js=  new JSONObject(response); will return correct json string?

Comment: `JsonObject js= new JSONObject(response);` doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry; You need a JSON lib for that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the same attribute name in your class and in your json. Otherwise you can use `@SerializedName("...")` to specify a different name

```
public class MyClass {
    @SerializedName("Number")
    public int number;

    @SerializedName("Date")
    public Long date;
}
```

Comment: Updated my question. The issue is with the extra `"`.

Comment: Your problem comes from your request (the `GET`) which returns a response with extra `"`.

Comment: It was actually the `GET` that was return a string instead of JSON. Fixed that and my Java code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Apply these steps to your response string

```
 String s=  response.toString();
 s = s.trim();
 s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
 s = s.replace("\\", "");
```

or

```
s .replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

so thats not the issue...

> just create one temp jsonobject with response string

i've updated your code

```
URL url = new URL(some_url_string);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   response.append(inputLine);
}
reader.close();

String s = response.toString();
JSONObject sObj=new JSONObject(s); 
// create this object and now pass this to serialize object using GSON
MyClass temp = new Gson().fromJson(sObj.toString(), MyClass.class);
```